# Replace all items with their counts

Tags: code-golf, array, counting

**Task:**

Given an array of numbers as input (you can choose what subset, such as integers or natural numbers), replace all items with the number of times they appear within the array. As an example, `[1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 8, 1]` would become `[3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3]`.

You can take input/produce output as arrays, lists, tuples, or any other reasonable representation of some numbers.

**Test cases:**

```
[1]                     [1]
[1, 2]                  [1, 1]
[1, 1]                  [2, 2]
[1, 4, 4]               [1, 2, 2]
[4, 4, 2]               [2, 2, 1]
[4, 4, 4, 4]            [4, 4, 4, 4]
[10, 20, 10, 20]        [2, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]   [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 8, 1]   [3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3]
```

**Other:**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer (in bytes) per language wins!

Comment: I feel like this is a dupe of something but that's probably just because it's a convenient sub-problem of a bunch of other things

Comment: Can the chosen subset be digits 0-9?

Comment: @Jonah I'm going to say no, just since it's so narrow.

Comment: A siller question on that same note, could the input be restricted to prime numbers? I don't see it being relevant to anything as it is, but if this exact question were posted in the dark days of `Ð€`, Jelly would still have had a 2-byter in `Pọ` :P

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 23 bytes

```python
lambda l:map(l.count,l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKjexQCNHLzm/NK9EJ0fzf3lGZk6qgqFVQVFmXolCmkZmXkFpiYam5v9ow1iuaEMdBSMIBeWZABGQZQJmGcFZUGFDA6AgEENoqH4wQlIGAA)

Comment: ...I forgot `map` was a thing, thanks for helping me save 5 bytes on my Python 3 answer!

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
&=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X822@P//aEMdBSMwAjJMdBQsgIxYAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F/Ntvi/S8j/aMNYrmhDHQUjCAXlmQARkGUCZhnBWVBhQwOgIBBDaKh@MEJVBhOFGGgBMh0A).

#### Explanation

```
     % Implicit input: numeric row vector
&=   % Matrix of all pairwise equality comparisons
s    % Sum of each column
     % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 36 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(x=>a.map(y=>t+=x==y,t=0)|t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQKMCxqi0tSvRtq2wta3UKbE10Kwp0fyfnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RphFtGKuAATQ1FfT1FYBSXOiKdRSMYnEo1lHAqt4Qh3ojkFFY1JsAUSx287FqMQFrMYrFYQU2V0G0oFoE1YIkheE2A6BxQAyhYzEtwuUjiBSSyag@QpH6DwA)

Comment: The one answer that doesn't use a counting builtin...

Answer (score 7):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 6 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
+/∘.=⍨
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=09Z/1DFDz/ZR7woA&f=S1MwVDACQkMFEwULBUMA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

```
+/∘.=⍨  dfn submission
  ∘.=   product table using equality
     ⍨  applied to the input on the left and the right
+/      reduce by addition / sum
```

Comment: Another take +/¨⊢=⊂

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 28 bytes

```
[ dup histogram substitute ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU8xDsIwDNz7intB1UYMCB6AWFgQE2IIwdCqtA2xM6Cqbw9pBSgIW7LuztbZvmojvQuH/Xa3WaEh19Edmrk3jFZLlbNoqVnqyK0jkad1dSdgenjqDDHW2ZAhxoAS4xepBKf6IuaHTVj9sLRbFlDFu6a@6n9yVifv5bxrDEdcvEUV7@5vTrdgf44viBfCKbTaIn5lmjy8AA)

It's a bit shorter than the version for squares:

```
[ dup [ '[ _ = ] count ] with map ]
```

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a sequence from the data stack as input and leaves a sequence on the data stack as output. Assuming `{ 1 4 4 }` is on the data stack when this quotation is called...

- `dup` Duplicate an object.

  **Stack:** `{ 1 4 4 } { 1 4 4 }`
- `histogram` Create a histogram from a sequence.

  **Stack:** `{ 1 4 4 } H{ { 1 1 } { 4 2 } }`
- `substitute` Take a sequence and an associative array and substitute elements in the sequence that have keys in the assoc with their values.

  **Stack:** `{ 1 2 2 }`

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
∋;?{∈ᵈ}ᶜ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/486uq3tqx91dDzc2lH7cNuc//@jow1jdRSiDXUUjKA0jG8CRCCmCZhphGDCJAwNgMJADKFhpoARksJYAA)

[Generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) the output through the output variable.

```
∋;          Pair some element of the input with
  ?         the input.
   {  }ᶜ    In how many ways is
    ∈ᵈ      the element an element of the input?
```

Using `ọ` comes out one byte longer:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
⟨ọ⟨∋h⟩∋⟩t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/4/mr3i4uxdIPurozng0fyWQApIl//9HRxvG6ihEG@ooGEFpGN8EiEBMEzDTCMGESRgaAIWBGELDTAEjJIWxAA)

Also [generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) the output through the output variable.

```
      ∋      Choose an element of the input.
  ⟨ h⟩       It is the first element of
   ∋         an element of
⟨ọ     ⟩     the list of pairs [element of input, how many times it occurs in input]
        t    the last element of which is the output.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

```
f=->*a{a.map{|e|a.count e}}
```

Testing:

```
p f[4,3,4]  #=> [2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Comment: Similar to the other answer, you need to wrap this in a function or lambda.

Answer (score 5):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 10 bytes

```
{.Bag{$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Ws8pMb1aJb629n9xYqWCkkq8gq2dQnWaAlBISSEtv0jBxtBOB0goGEEoKM9EwQTEAFIQCRADKmZooGBkoAAm7az/AwA)

`.Bag` generates a Bag (a set with multiplicity) from the input argument `$_`.  Then `{$_}` slices into that Bag with the original list, producing a list of the multiplicities of the elements of that list, in order.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
ċⱮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I96ON6/4fbn/UtObopIc7ZwDpyP//o6MNY3W4og11FIygNIxvAkQgpgmYaYRgwiQMDYDCQAyhYaaAEYrCWAA)

### How it works

```
ċⱮ - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
 Ɱ - For each element in L
ċ  -   Count the times it appears in L
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
vO
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=vO&inputs=%5B1%2C%202%2C%202%2C%201%2C%204%2C%208%2C%201%5D&header=&footer=)

Wow y'all using unicode in your golfing languages while I'm chilling in the ASCII zone.

### Explained

```
vO  # vectorise count over the input
    # essentially, [input.count(n) for n in input]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda l:[*map(l.count,l)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7dDoIgFL7Wpzh3QjGn5pVbb9EdcUGlkw2RGdR6ekJx60cY7Ox8v@iX6Ud1cB0c4ewkHy43DrKhu4FrJPPraJUhEjP37IVs4TTZtkkT4dXtg0sklLYG4fyupTAoYxmmBdvPM030JJRBgkCHBMaOlgxix@MpLQlULMYRWOmYm1azbaFrf1nEvSrqRbGpWAJCRVBsYr5xX1R4vX9hsr@Yz2/C8hsZxd8)

-5 bytes (indirectly) [thanks to xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224134/66833)!

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
/LQ
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FLQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+4%2C+4%5D%0A%5B4%2C+4%2C+2%5D%0A%5B4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%5D%0A%5B10%2C+20%2C+10%2C+20%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%5D&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
/LQ  | Full program
/LQQ | with implicit variables
-----+-------------------------------------
 L Q | replace each element d in input with
/ Q  | the count of d in input
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES2021), 35 bytes (not quite reasonable I/O)

```javascript
a=>a.map(n=>a[++(a[n]||=[0])[0],n])
```

Accept an array of <s>1 element array of</s> *negative* numbers. Return an array of 1 element array...

```javascript
f([-1, -2, -2, -1, -4, -8, -1]) // [[3], [2], [2], [3], [1], [1], [3]]
f([[-1], [-2], [-2], [-1], [-4], [-8], [-1]]) // [[3], [2], [2], [3], [1], [1], [3]]
```

<del>Just consider input / output as column vectors...</del>

---

## JavaScript (ES2021), 42 bytes

Add an extra `.flat()` to make it reasonable would cost +7 bytes (42 bytes in total)

```javascript
a=>a.map(n=>a[++(a[n]||=[0])[0],n]).flat()
```

That's too long.

Comment: Is `||=` a ES2021 feature? I don't remember seeing that before.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yes. `||=`, `&&=` and `??=` are ES2021 features. Logical `||=` and `&&=` are also supported by  ActionScript (ES4) long long ago.

Comment: Can't you use `flatMap`?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms flatMap will flat as soon as the array returns, not flat after map. <del>maybe we need a proposal about Array#mapFlat API to JavaScript.</del>

Comment: `a=>a.map(x=>a.filter(y=>x==y).length)` (37 bytes) would be a better substitute for the second solution.

Comment: @kamoroso94 There is [another JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224130) posted by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) using the similar approach.

Answer (score 4):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```lisp
(λ(b)(map(λ(y)(count(λ(x)(= x y))b))b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE5nBppKSmZealKqT91zi3WyNJUyM3sQDEqtTUSM4vzSsBsSs0NWwVKhQqNTWTwOi/JhcXSJ1CmoK6hoahJpcCDGgYKhihctFkTRRMkAWAXFQNIAE0NYYGCkYGCmASzSYgxKYeLAGyygJoO9C1AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
1#.=/~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1bPXr/mtyKXClJmfkK6QpaOgYasLYhgpGCKaJggmCYwhjAkURikwgEK7MQMHIAEIimQiE6OrAgiAbLIAGK8DAfwA)

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 9 bytes

```
{+/x=\:x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWlu/wjbGqqL2f5q6ho6htYKhghGIALNMFEysQQRIyAQCgcIGCkYGEBKsGggRcmAuSKOFgqHmfwA)

Comment: An alternative 9-byte answer is possible in ngn/k: [`{(#'=x)x}`](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpDWd22QrOi9n@auoaOobWCoYIRiACzTBRMrEEESMgEAoHCBgpGBhASrBoIEXJgLkijhYKh5n8A)

Comment: @coltim Thank you! So you make a dictionary with numbers/frequencies for keys/values and request the values according to the input keys?

Comment: Yep, exactly! It's possible to implement it in oK as well, but you would need to use `{(#:'=x)x}`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
f a=[sum[1|y<-a,y==x]|x<-a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7bCsIgGL7fU/xEsI3ssNhVze6D3kD@CyFX0ubGZqDQu5vbgk6K8ut39Mr7m6gq50rglPX3mmUPWyw5sZQafBh/RVdzqei5iSCRpEmLZVnzFjSX1apvuUrWNMY4LeaHi9AnqUQEldBgaCf4OZGLxQxn6W7Hjkrj3o4o@Ky2k0onpddRSwyxaQRDj2MZQmh5PGIZgS2GOAIvOuRm28E20rnfGHC/FPmo@KsYA6aKSfEX84n7oo3X@zNN/Il5/2Z6fEcG8Sc)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0KL//6MNdRSMwAjIMNFRsAAyYgE) Beats all other answers.

```
¢  # full program
¢  # number of times...
   # (implicit) each element in...
   # implicit input...
¢  # appears in...
   # implicit input
   # implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 22 bytes

```perl
s/\S+/grep$_==$&,@F/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPyZYWz@9KLVAJd7WVkVNx8FNPz31/39DBSMgNFQwUbBQMPyXX1CSmZ9X/F@3IBEA)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel 17, bytes

```
=COUNTIF(A1#,A1#)
```

Assuming `A1 = { .... }` then this works.  It's a longer, less flexible formula if the data in entered in individual cells.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 58 bytes

```java
l->l.stream().map(x->java.util.Collections.frequency(l,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZI9a8MwEEB3/wqNUrGPJGQoJPVSKBTayWPpoDqykStLinQOMSW/3ZU/kg7t0IBzSAjdHU8PThU/8KTafXaytsYhqcIdGpQKXqTHTfQr7dEJXsPdH6Wi0TlKo/tiZJsPJXOSK@49eeVSk6@IhJjyHjmG42DkjtShSjN0Updv74S70rOxt4@nCbrtfbbPGkUpXBqTbPC4JFJSPHQqSc@ClEHNLT0m6Y/fo1FKDDAPhRP7Rui8pSo@MtZtLg9mrUdRg2kQbFBCpWkB3FrV0l4BTEGXjEE@wugENc4Dmr6BMsauo8VkNTdwdsN1WLMy1wNzdQPm7KrLRRANezxnn/2wbqV@5o8jvP/3zzhFp@4b)

## Java, 56 bytes

```java
l->l.stream().map(x->l.stream().filter(y->y==x).count())
```

This only works for integers in the Integer Cache (-128 to 127, by default).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZLBasMwDIbveQof7dGYtvQwaJLLYFDoTjmOHTzXCU4d29hKaRh99sxO2sHYDhukQkZYkn99IDfsxNLmcBxka40D1IQ77UAqupcetsmPtAcnWEsffilVneYgjY7FxHbvSnLEFfMevTCp0UeCgl3zHhiEcDLygNpQxSU4qevXN8Rc7cnUG@35KppFnmynQdTCFQtUjhzZ3ui6KFCVDyotbnSY0JZZfP6WqaQC4XCfFn2enwnlptOACRm2X7PK3oNoqemA2kADSuOKMmtVj@N0aiq8IvGlUoIDfpqicZ6CiQ1BjfxPbYHWcwvOTrgJPqvmZtRc30FzdtTVMoCGM8XZdz/6vdBv@tMKH//8My7JZfgE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
ec
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLUpMhDCh_wdZoQx0FIzACMkx0FCyAjFiIJAA)

```
ec : implicit input array
e  : map the input to the following:
 c :   count the occurrences of the number in the input
   : implicit output
```

Thought I'd try an easy and short problem for my first Thunno answer.

Comment: Nice! I didn't see your answer before answering, but I came up with another 2 character solution: `Dc`.

Comment: @TheThonnu Can you explain how your version works? My understanding is: it duplicates the array. Then `c` automatically maps over both arrays at once. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, `c` will vectorise over a list. Your one isn't *supposed* to work, since `e` should pop the list, but somehow it does...

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```julia
~a=@.count(==(a),[a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZGxCoMwEIb3PMWBi4KURh26BFx8g25yQyhCW2wtTaROvnp6JhRieuFCjvzf/fkh93m8abk4t2rVHi7T/LS5Urkuyl5j4TLoFv14jYNozXX6wNrLEipf1DQlnKhBITI4D8Ya0WpjhrfdOARmKQWkxBh5IY955x0peXLLk5CUrEHWM4UbD1fI2yYZApyab3CkxEmO5EE7nPhnziQPt7uHouQ7hRuMfiUM1j@l9iJVjcJ9AQ)

-3 bytes thanks to MarcMush: replace `Ref(a)` with `[a]`

Comment: -3 bytes: `[a]` instead of `Ref(a)`

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 26 bytes

```r
ave(a,a<-scan(),FUN=table)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7EsVSNRJ9FGtzg5MU9DU8ct1M@2JDEpJ1Xzv6GCERAaKpgoWCgY/gcA)

`ave` takes a vector `x`, an arbitrary number of grouping variables `...`, and a function `FUN`, and replaces each element of `x` with the result of applying `FUN` to the group containing that element.

I've also found a number of 26 byte variants with `FUN=sum`; they differ only in the way they generate a vector of ones with length `length(a)`.

```r
ave(a^0,a<-scan(),FUN=sum)
ave(a,a<-scan(),FUN=sum)/a
ave(a|1,a<-scan(),FUN=sum)
```

Comment: Great, and a nice showcase of a previously-unused-by-me R function

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <sup>47</sup> 45 bytes

```
{++f[l[++n]=$1]}END{for(x in l)print f[l[x]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Wls7LTonWls7L9ZWxTC21tXPpTotv0ijQiEzTyFHs6AoM69EAaSiIja29v9/Qy4jIDTkMuGy4DIEAA)

*-2 thanks to cnamejj*

Comment: This is so similar I thought it made more sense to post as a comment instead of a new answer.  The assignment can be golfed a bit more.

{++f[l[++n]=$1]}END{for(x in l)print f[l[x]]}

Comment: Thanks, nice golf.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
£è¥X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=o%2bilWA&input=WzEsMiwyLDEsMyw0LDQsMl0tUQ)

maps input by returning number of occurrence in input

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>84</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>81</s></sup> 75 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)!!!

```c
b;i;j;f(*a,l){for(i=-1;++i<l;printf("%d ",b))for(b=j=l;j--;)b-=a[i]!=a[j];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZPrboMwDIX/8xQeUiXSglauRUvZHmSrJnqhCsroVKrdEK8@ZpK0UG@roA7@Tk4sy9l4G5lX@65bc8FLXjjT3JWsKQ5HR2Sez2czsZT89SiqU@HYky3Y7pqxHq@zMpO89DzO1l6WP4rVDf6XK952bwexBbXHwRem@fGYf7rQr@WuYlZjAf7QBBQXkMGcY1j2mAOeyaCBy6H1ZGvj7gcb7DsbV8oOz2McWqu1rN7jJReVc3buE6ddfXqeP67Qu/FbPuR8k3MhGKeDS/pKHV7SET5jEmkSKXJlFY8J3ZYYwzluwlfHsWAx1Keev21SotIFpqr66x5IrazF1@5QOLot7NZ8Ts23C2PuE@4THhAeEB4SHhIeER4RHhMeE54QnhC@IHxBeEp4yoamTVXXat003R3XDI6JgYmhiZGJsYmJiQsTU2M@zHu13X2YmVfL5bi6@rq4mqkL0euYstEjPlSLRrpipVnxMQZpKE4BxefrZTOSc04uSPZbCN49jMXFf8Kn6izD69l9bwqZ7@vOe/8B)

Inputs a pointer to an array and its length (because array pointers in C don't carry any length info) and prints the occurrence counts.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 56 bytes

```php
fn($a)=>array_map(fn($e)=>array_count_values($a)[$e],$a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/NCoMwDL73KXLooYWCU7w5tweRIGWreJgu6Crs6bs62fCnLSmBfH8JteTOV2qJMd5ACa7pBdeyvOhh0O@60yTmiflPbk/bv@pJP6wZZ2bFDSrfXcHYpIf6bjsSvBFVinB4UhaQJOCxHVdBhjGuggA9jdGz2epAz31hxD2gyL@KDGMBx5UWxTbmp1hhu8VO3sv/pWMgJnzNAqxsd9dsMPcB)

As usual, those "array_" PHP prefixes are ruining the golfing :P

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 32 bytes

Nothing special

```cs
a=>a.Select(x=>a.Count(y=>x==y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXEh2ro@Dpmleam1qUmJSTChKys1NIA8oq2Cr8T7S1S9QLTs1JTS7RqACxnfNL80o0Km3tKmxtKzU1/1tzOefnFefnpOqFF2WWpPpk5qVqFJcUZeal63nlZ@ZpKOko6YBN08hLLY@OVahWMFSo1dTUJEOfgY6CERCDaXLNAGoFIyDDREfBQgfmmv8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

Right language, right time.

```
Ψ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//9yKD3OnLvj/P9pQwQgIDRVMFCwUDGMB)

Explanation:

```
Ψ  # Apply next token to all in list
  # Count element in list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 23 bytes

```sh
xargs -I. grep -c . f<f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@G@X9r8isSi9WEHXU08hvSi1QEE3WUFPIc0m7f9/Qy4jIDTkMuGy4DL8DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io),  <s>34</s>  27 bytes

```arturo
$->a[map a=>[get tally a&]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?kQNhdw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 bytes

```
Đɔ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISTU/7/jzbUUTACIyDDREfBAsiIBQA)

```
Đ      implicit input; duplicate
 ɔ     for each item in input, count occurrences in input; implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 13 bytes

```
seq(sum(I=Ans),I,1,dim(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 103 bytes

```go
func f(l[]int)[]int{m:=make(map[int]int)
for _,e:=range l{m[e]++}
for i,e:=range l{l[i]=m[e]}
return l}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVJBbsMgEJR65BUoJ5ykTRPnEEXyH3pHqKKRsawAthA-WX5JL1alPqJPaV_TBVzFsXERGDEzO7ssfv8oqv6r5pcrL3KseKlRqerK2KeVUHb12VjxePouRKMvWBBJWalt4r-tOmeKX3OieE3h7BkkKoNft_k5M1yDoWwVzdlm03miHBOSlixzbIdMbhujsexCup-HN5_PVUMS3KLdGtE9w7EBOHBbfIjQDh_oWDQ9uDBPH2FOFd41KI5eMUvhDUKKoJjZjHFI9Ax6WGFnE5tbNeFwbxnFR-pwidNwU5r-4amnYKYMrXfoxcArSU0ECW-475JkDkLkAr6kd-XEqKFzy9RS4H2vlqqcNORf2a1DTjb8an0f9l8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
c
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUIxJTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAxJTJDJTIwNCUyQyUyMDglMkMlMjAxJTVEJmZsYWdzPQ==)

Just the `c`ount command, vectorised over the array implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), 77 bytes

```
f(a)=\sum_{n=[1...a.length]}^{[1...a.length]}(total(\left\{a=a[n],0\right\}))
```

[Try it online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2sn5kve00v) Takes in a list as input, and outputs a new list as per the specifications. The linked graph uses an action to replace the list with the function's output.

Comment: [26 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8zp8luop1l?nographpaper)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 44 Bytes

```
n.stream().map(e->frequency(n1,e)).toList();
```

with `n1` beeing a copy of `n` and static import of `java.util.Collections.*`

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 29 bytes

```powershell
($a=$args)|%{($a-eq$_).count}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJPa4QwEMXvfophSYsBLVX30IsgSHvopaW7t1IW12a7FNdYE9uC@tntmBBZ/7ANkeCb33szEQv@w0pxZFnmprxkHTmEdWeTJCRJ@SFoc1Xji8u@yI7epLzKZdu1lhXZFuByIjuyPerAfPU6PYMc8Oec0qect8T5vX/MrXFPUN1ngq4V6s9QX6HeHJ0Gj/TzGW4xAR99GocJXphYq6Mmy/qSTd/4Tn@fyA6MHqgS7gBtFBp44OV9kh7dp/0nSyXUKotIJmScCOYAYb8FFtg7hEB2uloyUWUShWtygMiwqvb6vIkrIflJ571FOrBfmypNmRBos01CAzHPv1kpt9x9FDwHN@anAouCAv5FCA7dL6BDh9UWR4F@llU/rRnsgnewvpgr/T@a8rRWa3V/)

Answer (score 2):

#### Common Lisp, 42

```
(lambda(x)(mapcar(lambda(u)(count u x))x))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 5 bytes

```
_NgMg
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhZL4_3SfdMhbKjQ-mhDHSMgNNQx0bHQMYSpBAA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
    g  ; List of command-line args
   M   ; Map to each:
_N     ;  Number of occurrences of that argument in...
  g    ;  ... the list of command-line args
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
ＩＥθ№θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQKNQR8E5vxQoAmRkagKB9f//0dGGOgpGYARkmOgoWAAZsbH/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ     Input array
 Ｅ      Map over elements
   №    Count of
     ι  Current element in
    θ   Input arrray
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
€¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaQ4v@/4821FEwAiMgw0RHwQLIiAUA)

### Explained

```
€¢   # [input.count(n) for n in input]
```

Comment: [you had the chance to (ab)use automatic vectorization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224144/94066)

Comment: @Makonede so why did you post as a separate answer instead of just leaving a golfing suggestion? Usually when someone has a similar method but shorter they leave a comment showing how to remove bytes.

Comment: Actually, I had posted the answer before even seeing yours, so I would've left the suggestion but it was too late

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 22 bytes

```scala
a=>a.map(a count _.==)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1cfjp8GNRKqFo2KDsrzn1Q)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 12 bytes

```
Counts@#/@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zm/NK@k2EFZ30FZ7X9AUWZeSbSyrl2ag3KsWl1wcmJeXTVXtWGtDpDQMYJQUJ6JjgmIAaQgEiAGVMzQQMfIQAdMQnUCIbI8WABkhAXQNK7a/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 36 bytes

```
f(v)=apply(x->sum(i=1,#v,x==v[i]),v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY69CsMwDIT3vkYXGy4Q2xm6qC8SPGRpMSRgWmrSp3cl/zTtIu4@3QnF5RGGe8z5ppKmJcb1rfbh@nxtKpDBOWEnSnPwGklLajZeE/E8iYatDt3XrWVe/YSpJTpj0lpMWk9YT3Zd@iPsiDK/jeO26N/mPzky8sWlfeYKccwMnM8f)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 45 bytes

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(COUNT(A:A))))
```

Input is in column A. The formula goes anywhere not in column A.

`COUNT(A:A)` counts the numeric entries.
`SEQUENCE(~)` creates an array from 1 to whatever that count was.
`INDEX(A:A,~)` pulls the inputs one at a time, thanks to the sequence input.
`COUNTIF(A:A,~)` counts the inputs that match the one it just pulled.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [6 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
█Â(ÂÍL
```

Found some pretty major precedence bugs... so that's why I'm a day late

## Explained

Unpacked: `@a{/:=a`

```
  _       STDIN; implied
@         Bind following to each value
  a{         Block with key of 'a'
     /:      Bind next arg with the arg after, use truthiness to filter and then count
          _    Current value, implicit
        =      Equals
          a    Current value of map bind (defined by block)
        _    It's binded to STDIN
  }
```

Came up with some alternatives when I got bored from fixing the bug, here are some

## Arn, 8 bytes

```
ñ=èÍù«Á&
```

Unpacked: `@a{+{=a}\` (Replace each val with a mapped for equality + folded version of stdin)

## Arn, 8 bytes

```
hLdŠÅk$'
```

Unpacked: `@a{+\(@=a` (Same as last one but written a different way)

## Arn, 6 bytes

```
╔½†Œ#ç
```

Unpacked: `@a{$=a&#` (Very similar to the actual answer, but uses filter and a binded size suffix. Compression shaved two bytes off of this, instead of the one byte my real answer lost from compression, which is why they're the same length)

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, 32 bytes

```matlab
@(x)table(histcounts(x)).Var1(x)
```

...assuming inputting only integer numbers from 1 to 50. Rules says I can choose a subset.
To work for integers from 1 to 65536 (2<sup>16</sup>) you need few extra bytes and code like that:

```matlab
@(x)table(histcounts(x,'BinMethod','int')).Var1(x)
```

Both solutions are anonymous functions.
The fragment of code `table(...).Var1(x)` is a trick allowing for indexing the function output without saving it to a variable. Normally one would do something like that:

```matlab
y = histcounts(x);
return y(x)
```

but anonymous functions doesn't allow for that and full function would be longer.

The solution unfortunatelly doesn't work for Octave, because it doesn't have `histcounts` implemented. :(

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.65 bytes

```
Dc
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLXJIhDCh_wdZoQx0FIzACMkx0FCyAjFiIJAA)

Or, **\$1 \log_{256}(96) \approx\$ 0.82 bytes with the `D` flag!**: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6FguTITSUu2BrtKGOghEYARkmOgoWQEYsRBIA)

`D` duplicates the (implicit) input, and `c` gets the count of each one (vectorises automatically).

*Edit: Just realised that there's another Thunno answer here. I'll keep this undeleted, though, since it is different from the other answer.*

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 2 bytes

```
ᵐĈ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fksfbp1wpGNJcVJyMVRkwc3waMNYrmhDHSMwCWGb6JgAaSAJFgXREBFDAx0jAx0wCdEDhEiyYD5ItwXQHIj5AA)

```
ᵐĈ
ᵐ   Map
 Ĉ  Count
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 5 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
⊏∶⍘⊚.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oqP4oi24o2Y4oqaLgoKZiBbMV0KZiBbMSAyXQpmIFsxIDQgNF0KZiBbNCA0IDJdCmYgWzQgNCA0IDRdCmYgWzEwIDIwIDEwIDIwXQpmIFsxIDIgMiA0IDQgNCA0XQpmIFsxIDIgMiAxIDQgOCAxXQ==)

Works with natural numbers.

```
⊏∶⍘⊚.
    .  # duplicate
  ⍘⊚   # inverse where (occurrences)
 :     # flip
⊏      # select
```

Comment: Alternative 5: `/+⊞=.`

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 80 bytes

```
SELECT c FROM (SELECT a b,COUNT(*)c FROM @ GROUP BY a)x JOIN @ ON a=b ORDER BY i
```

## Example Input

Requires something like this for input

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (a int, i int identity)
INSERT INTO @ VALUES (1), (2), (2), (4), (4), (4), (4)
```

## Explanation

Group by the number and count them up. Then join back to the original list so that we can output in the correct order.